# How can I get special characters with Web Client in WP?

Tags: html, dynamic, windows-phone, message, webclient

I want to make dynamic message grid in my application's mainpage and I am getting it from my domain's html file. For example;

```
html
body
----Böşç Hello----
/body
/html
```

(I did not write <> tags for understanding.)

and I am getting them with my WebClient. But it is not getting this words "ö,ş,ç" correctly.

How can I do it? or have you any other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tweaking the encoding?

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```